# how to stop retry HTTP call when server servers respond with 200 status codes using guzzle retry middleware?

Tags: php, guzzle6

Following code throws an error "**paremeter 4 `&$options`  expected to be a reference, value given"**

This code is from [guzzle_retry_middleware#on-retry-callback](https://github.com/caseyamcl/guzzle_retry_middleware#on-retry-callback)

I wanted to stop the guzzle retry call after receiving `self::STATUS_DRAFT === $document->status` with **response 200**

```
$listener = function(int $attemptNumber, float $delay, RequestInterface $request, array &$options, ?ResponseInterface $response)
{
    $document = \json_decode();

    if (self::STATUS_DRAFT === $document->status)
    {
        return $options['retry_enabled'] = false;
    }
};

$stack = HandlerStack::create();
$stack->push(GuzzleRetryMiddleware::factory([
    'on_retry_callback' => $listener,
    'retry_on_status'   =>[429, 503, 200]
]));

$response = $guzzleClient->get($url, ['handler' => $stack]);
```

Comment: On `retry_on_status` you have included 200, which means it will retry for the status code 200. Have you tried removing the 200 status code from that?

Comment: it should call event in the 200 request that is my requirement.

Answer (score 2):

This test code seems to work fine for me. I created a request that just randomly spits out a number, which is used in the retry callback.

I'm using PHP 7.3 and the latest version of Guzzle and the middleware. If you're getting an error about the `$options` variable, try isolating this code on your environment and confirm there's no version mismatch.

```
use GuzzleHttp\Client;
use GuzzleHttp\HandlerStack;
use GuzzleRetry\GuzzleRetryMiddleware;
use Psr\Http\Message\RequestInterface;
use Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface;

error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');

$stack = HandlerStack::create();
$stack->push(GuzzleRetryMiddleware::factory());

$listener = function(int $attemptNumber, float $delay, RequestInterface &$request, array &$options, ResponseInterface $response) {
    $doc = json_decode($response->getBody()->getContents());
    echo "<br>Received {$doc->status} so ";

    if ($doc->status < 50) {
        $options['retry_enabled'] = false;
        echo "stopping";
        return;
    }
    echo "retrying";
};

$client = new Client([
    'handler' => $stack,
    'on_retry_callback' => $listener,
    'retry_on_status'   => [200]
]);

$response = $client->get('https://eouqfts30zafzos.m.pipedream.net/');
```

And I get this response

```
Received 69 so retrying
Received 68 so retrying
Received 31 so stopping
```

Here's my composer.json file

```
{
    "require": {
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^7.0",
        "caseyamcl/guzzle_retry_middleware": "^2.7"
    }
}
```